# Are points on max. two lines?

Tags: delphi, geometry, line, pascal

I have a time problem with my program. Given a set of points, it has to say whether all of those points are lying on two different lines.

I wrote code, which has points in array and removes one by one and try calculate it's vector.

But this solution is slow, because it must control all cases of lines. On input with 10,000 points it takes over 10 seconds.

Can someone please tell me if, is here better solution for this problem?

I made this code in Pascal:

```
    uses
  math;

type
  TPoint = record
    x, y: real;
  end;

  TList = array of TPoint;

function xround(value: real; places: integer): real;
var
  muldiv: real;
begin
  muldiv := power(10, places);
  xround := round(value * muldiv) / muldiv;
end;

function samevec(A, B, C: TPoint): boolean;
var
  bx, by: real; // vec A -> B
  cx, cy: real; // vec A -> C
  lb, lc: real; // len AB, len AC
begin
  bx := B.x - A.x;
  by := B.y - A.y;
  cx := C.x - A.x;
  cy := C.y - A.y;

  lb := sqrt(bx * bx + by * by);
  lc := sqrt(cx * cx + cy * cy);

  // normalize
  bx := xround(bx / lb, 3);
  by := xround(by / lb, 3);
  cx := xround(cx / lc, 3);
  cy := xround(cy / lc, 3);

  samevec := ((bx = cx) and (by = cy)) or ((bx = -cx) and (by = -cy));
end;

function remove(var list: TList; idx: integer): TPoint;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  remove.x := 0;
  remove.y := 0;
  if idx < length(list) then
    begin
      remove := list[idx];
      for i := idx to length(list) - 2 do
        list[i] := list[i + 1];
      setlength(list, length(list) - 1);
    end;
end;

var
  i, j, lines: integer;
  list, work: TList;
  A, B: TPoint;

begin
  while not eof(input) do
    begin
      setlength(list, length(list) + 1);
      with list[length(list) - 1] do
        readln(x, y);
    end;

  if length(list) < 3 then
    begin
      writeln('ne');
      exit;
    end;

  lines := 0;

  for i := 1 to length(list) - 1 do
    begin
      work := copy(list, 0, length(list));

      lines := 1;

      B := remove(work, i);
      A := remove(work, 0);
      for j := length(work) - 1 downto 0 do
        if samevec(A, B, work[j]) then
          remove(work, j);
      if length(work) = 0 then
        break;

      lines := 2;

      A := remove(work, 0);
      B := remove(work, 0);
      for j := length(work) - 1 downto 0 do
        if samevec(A, B, work[j]) then
          remove(work, j);
      if length(work) = 0 then
        break;

      lines := 3; // or more
    end;

  if lines = 2 then
    writeln('YES')
  else
    writeln('NO');
end.
```

Thanks, Ferko

APPENDED:

```
program line;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  math,
  sysutils;

type point=record
    x,y:longint;
  end;

label x;

var
Points,otherPoints:array[0..200001] of point;
n,n2,i,j,k,i1,i2:longint;

function sameLine(A,B,C:point):boolean;
var
  ABx,ACx,ABy,ACy,k:longint;
begin
  ABx:=B.X-A.X;
  ACx:=C.X-A.X;
  ABy:=B.Y-A.Y;
  ACy:=C.Y-A.Y;
  k:=ABx*ACy-ABy*ACx;
  if (k=0) then sameLine:=true
    else sameLine:=false;
  end;


begin
readln(n);
if (n<=4) then begin
  writeln('YES');
  halt;
  end;

for i:=1 to n do readln(Points[i].x,Points[i].y);

for i:=1 to 5 do for j:=i+1 to 5 do for k:=j+1 to 5 do if not (sameLine(Points[i],Points[j],Points[k])) then begin
  i1:=i;
  i2:=j;
  goto x;
  end;

writeln('NO');
halt; 

x:
n2:=0;
for i:=1 to n do begin
  if ((i=i1) or (i=i2)) then continue;
  if not sameLine(Points[i1],Points[i2],Points[i]) then begin
    inc(n2,1);
    otherPoints[n2]:=Points[i];
    end;
  end;

if (n2<=2) then begin
  writeln('YES');
  halt;
  end;

for i:=3 to n2 do begin
  if not sameLine(otherPoints[1],otherPoints[2],otherPoints[i]) then begin
    writeln('NO');
    halt;
    end;
  end;
writeln('YES');
end.
```

Comment: could you explain why the output is yes, I really didn't understand the relation

Comment: @Nasreddine output is yes, because points are lying on 2 red lines on picture. When there will be [12,12] too, out will be no, because these points can't lying on 2 lines.

Comment: so you have two lines and an array of points lets say 10000 points and you want to see if all the points belong to one of the lines. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Nasreddine yes, I want to find out, if all of points are lying on one or two lines. But I don't know, between which points these lines are. In input are only coordinates of points.

Comment: and how do you know if point A(0,1) is on line 1 or not

Comment: @Nasreddine it is the task. Find out, if all points lay on maximum two lines. I try two points as lime and another if are on this line. And this for all points.

Comment: The reason why I'm asking you this silly questions is that you could drive a lot of lines from the example you gave if you don't know the coordinates of at least two points from the line you want to test against then the hall thing is pretty useless when you have 10000 points

Comment: if you want to see if 10000 point are in the same line then that is easy job. Find the equation of the line using two points and test the rest of points against that and you are done

Comment: @Nasreddine Thank you, I try this tomorrow and I say, if it works.

Comment: Your picture has only points with integer coordinates. Is it necessary to take real variables? Note: the comparison of two real numbers is not simply the `=` sign. How precesely must a point belong to the equation describing the line? Is `Round` enough?

Comment: A much better formula to see if three points are on the same line: `function OnSameLine( const A,B,C : TPoint): Boolean;
begin
  // Result := dxAB*dyAC - dxAC*dyAB < epsilon;
  Result := Math.SameValue((A.x-B.x)*(A.y-C.y),(A.x-C.x)*(A.y-B.y));
end;`

Comment: Basically this formula compares the slopes of a line between point A and B with the slope of a line between A and C.

Comment: @LURD not just three points they could be 10000

Comment: @asd-tm Points have only integer coordinates

Comment: @Nasreddine I tried this `vector[i]:=(abs((y-points[i].y)/(x-points[i].x)));` but I get division by zero, if points have same x coordinate.

Comment: Comment on your appended code. The first five points must be distinct i.e. pt1<>pt2<>pt3 etc. Otherwise Pt1 (1,1) and Pt2 (1,1) will seem to define a uique line but they don't. You have to select these 5 points not according to their ids but according to their different coordinates. Example: how many lines of three points does this set have: (1,1)(1,1)(2,1)(1,2)(2,2)?

Comment: For the purpose of further optimization it might be useful to (q)sort the array by one of coordinates and delete the repeating points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the answer to the Q should be devided into two parts.

I. How to know that the given three points belong to the same line?
The answer to this part of the Q was given by @Lurd and then expanded by Mbo.
Let us name their solution `function BelongToOneLine(Pnts: array [1..3] of TPoint): boolean;` We can consider this part solved.

II. How to decrease time consumption of the algorithm or in other words: how to avoid calling `BelongToOneLilne` with every possible combination of points as parameters?

Here is the algorithm.

1. We select 5 *distinct* points from the task set. 5 is enough (check combination possibilities).
2. We find the answer to the question if there are at least three points from given five that belong to a single line.

   *if No -* then we do not need to iterate the remaining poins - the answer is that we require more then two lines.

   *if Yes -* (say poins Pt1, Pt2 and Pt3 belong to the same line and Pt4 and Pt5 - don't).
3. Then we store the points that do not belong to the line Pt1-Pt2-Pt3 from the group-of-five in a distinct array of "outsider" points (or store their indexes in the main array). It may have `Length = 0` by the end of this step. This will not affect the rest of the algo.
4. We get the boolean result of the function `BelongToOneLine([Pt1, Pt2, Pt[i]])`.

   *if Yes -* we skip the point - it belongs to the line Pt1-Pt2-Pt3.

   *if No -* we store this point in the "outsiders" array.
5. We watch the length of the OutsidersArray.

   *if it is <= 2* then the answer to the whole Q is Yes, they do belong to 2 or less lines.

   *if >2* then we iterate the function `BelongToOneLine([OutsiderPt1, OutsiderPt2, OutsiderPt[i]])` until High(OutsiderArray) or until when `OutsiderPt[i]` does not belong to OutsiderPt1-OutsiderPt2 line. All points of OutsiderArray must belong to the same line otherwise the answer to the whole Q will be negative.

*Math note*

Without optimization the inerations count will be `n! / ((n - k)! * k!)`.
With the optimization it will be:
`5! / ((5-3)! * 3!)` + `(n - 3)` + `P(q)outsiders * n` that is about 15000 for n = 10000. Most negative count - about 20000.

*And another optimization note*

Replace declaration of TPoint with integer variables.

Comment: @Ferko The rules at SO do not allow to give external links. Should you decide to give extra code you'd better edit your question and add a section called for instance 'Appended' or something like that. The community will not visit the external link given by you.

Answer (score 1):

Three points A, B and C lie on the same straight line, if vectors AB and AC are collinear or anti-collinear. We can check for collinearity using [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of vectors - it should be zero.

@LU RD already described this approach is comment, but author probably missed it.

Note that method doesn't suffer from division by zero - there is no division at all.

```
 ABx := B.X - A.X;
 ACx := C.X - A.X;
 ABy := B.Y - A.Y;
 ACy := C.Y - A.Y;
 Cross := ABx * ACy - ABy * ACx;
 // for integer coordinates
 if Cross = 0 then 
    A,B,C are collinear
```

If coordinates are float, one must consider some tolerance level. Variants:

```
 //better if available:
 if Math.IsZero(Cross)
 if Math.SameValue(Cross, 0)
 //otherwise
 if Abs(Cross) <= SomeEpsilonValue
```

If coordinate range is very large, numerical error might be significant, so it is worth to normalize tolerance by squared magnitude of coordinate differences:

```
 if Math.IsZero(Cross / Max(ABx * ABx + ABy * ABy, ACx * ACx + ACy * ACy))
```

Comment: It is exactly what @Lurd said in his comment yesterday.

Comment: `ACx := C.X = A.X;` I guess  should be `ACx := C.X - A.X;` and `ACy` has the same typo.

Comment: @asd-tm Typo corrected. Yes, I saw LU RD comment and upvoted it yesterday to emphasize good approach, but seems author missed or ignored it.

Comment: @MBo I just want to say that your answer is completely right when you answer _How to know if 3 points belong to the same line?_ but is this the question OP asking. As far as I can see three points is just an example and a way to know if  **10000 points belong to the same line**. think about that. Are we looking to the same problem as the OP or not?

Comment: @Nasreddine Abdelillah Galfout   Author has to specify his specific case. For example, he receives many points sets for the same lines. Or static point set and many line sets. Or something else.

Comment: I think the complexity increases exponentially when many points are involved and the number of lines is not fixed. To find a line we have to pick two fixed points and test against the others until we find a matching point. If not found, we have to replace one of the fixed points and start over again. There is an algorithm that can transform a set of coordinates in order to identify straight lines (or other shapes as well) called the [Hough Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform). It might be worth investigating if that is a better approach to this problem.

Comment: Another approach is to start making a list of the slope of two randomly picked points, and as soon as there is a duplicate, start trying to find if a line could be eliminated from the set of coordinates.

Comment: @Nasreddine I guess there are two problems within the Q. And gave the details of my vision in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Search Results
Featured snippet from the web
For n=1: you need two lines to intersect, so the maximum number of intersections is 0. n=2: Two distinct lines will always intersect in at most one point irrespective of dimensions. ... Explanation: Each set of 2 lines can intersect at one point. Or one point is common intersection for 2 lines.